# Add missing button mapping

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am creating a qml app for android and run into the following problem when trying to catch button presses:

When I press the `volume up`, `volume down` or the `home` button. The following snipped prints: `0` which means the key event is unknown (Based on the [QKeyEvent docu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#QKeyEvent))

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    console.log(event.key);
}
```

I also see this warning in logcat when pressing the `home` button:

```
Unhandled key code  3 !
```

or this warning when pressing the `volume up` button:

```
Unhandled key code  252 !
```

---

**My Question:** How can I add a handler/mapper for this key codes ?

Example I want to map the key code 3 to Qt.Key_Home in order to receive the correct key event in `Keys.onPressed`

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible : https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/plugins/platforms/android/androidjniinput.cpp#L748-L750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to 'remap' the key codes my devices uses to the key codes Qt expects by:

1. Copy `$QT/src/android/java/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/binding/` into your proejct folder.
2. Change `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR` in your `.pro` to point to the this folder.
3. rename the package name of all the classes in your new `android/binding/` folder to fit the package name of your qml app.
4. add your custom mapping code in `onKeyDown()`:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
       //do the remapping for the home button
       if(keyCode == 3) {
           keyCode = 122;
       }

       if (QtApplication.m_delegateObject != null && QtApplication.onKeyDown != null)
           return (Boolean) QtApplication.invokeDelegateMethod(QtApplication.onKeyDown, keyCode, event);
       else
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not near my QML machine but of top of my head do something like this.

Create a global object with required key codes like..

```
QtObject {
    id: key_code
    property int volume_up:         252
    property int volume_down:       <key_code_val>
    property int key_home:          3
}
```

Then use it like..

```
Keys.onPressed {
    if (event.key === key_code.volume_up) {
        //Do volume up handling..
        event.accepted = true
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly this is not the solution I am looking for / won't work because **event.key is always 0** for key_home, vlolume_up etc.

Comment: Have you tried.. if(event.key === Qt.Key_VolumeUp)? Also Qt.Key_Home and Qt.Key_VolumeDown

Comment: yes. Like I wrote in my question: event.key is **0** when I press these hardware buttons since their mapping is unknown to Qt. (I guess that my device is using different key mappings than most other android phones)

Comment: Sorry missed that key part to your question.  What happens if you try.. Keys.onVolumeDownPressed: console.log("volume down").  See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#volumeDownPressed-signal

Comment: np. also tried: `Keys.onVolumeDownPressed` -> which does not get called. (Since Qt does recognize the press of the volumeDownButton as the volumeDownButton)